# Can Numeric Fields be the Target of SQL Injection Attacks?

Tags: sql-server, performance, parameters, sql-injection

I am running into a problem where I am getting a significant performance increase in my SQL Server queries by replaceing parameters with hard values. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE RowNumber >= 101 AND ID < 200
```

is significantly faster than the following:

```
DECLARE @Start int = 101;
DECLARE @End Start int = 200;

SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE RowNumber >= @Start AND RowNumber < @End
```

The first one runs in about 2s where the 2nd one runs in 15s. So my question is, am I safe to use hard values if they are numeric and pnly parameterize strings? I do not believe this is a matter of indices because the RowNumber column is already indexed as a non clustered index. I am not that familiar with all of the SQL injection techniques, but I have been using parameters for all input values for years in an attempt to avoid SQL injection attacks. I never quite realized there was any potential for decreased performance such as this by using parameters.

I have also seen some questions on SO about performance decreases using parameters but I have not seen any definitive answers on how to resolve the problem.

Comment: It is not clear from your question how the query is constructed - where are you getting the values for `@Start` and `@End`? How are you building the query string?

Comment: Those are variables not parameters. Try adding `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to get it to sniff the actual variable values.

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of anything else, I'd say that given this statement "I am not that familiar with all of the SQL injection techniques" then you should always play it safe and continue with your parameterised queries.

I do a talks on SQL Injection Attacks at user groups and I don't consider that I know everything. I thought I knew a lot and about the various ways an attack can take place, but I even had one guy come up to me after a talk and tell me about an attack that happened at a company where he worked where the attack came via a **paper form** that was read by an OCR machine. I would never have ever considered that form of attack previously.

Attacks happen in all sorts of strange ways, and even if you've thought of everything you can, some one else will always manage to think of some other way to attack the system.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server evaluates some constant expressions early to improve query performance. This is referred to as constant folding.

In your query above, as before compiling the query the constants will be evaluated and optimizer does not need to do anything.But in case of parameters the optimizer has to compile it at every run time.

Answer (score 0):

Numeric fields are dangerous because comments (**//** or **/**) and *spaces* serve to make SQL injection (attacks)

Many sites let a user enter in a reserved area if user and password match.

Suppose a crazy site that uses a numeric field for the password:

```
 .....  Where User='James' and Pass=123
```

Even if one validates a user input in Javascript, it's very easy change the post values:
So,  one can "inject" the below piece instead of 123

```
             123  or 1=1
```

All records are returned. Many sites detect this situation, however it's very common that the user field be  "user" or "username". So one can try "user" and other common field names in the structure down

```
            12  or 1=1  and User='James'
```

In this case, only the desired record will be returned!

A simple solution for number fields is use single quotations:

```
                  Select User='James' and Pass='123'
```

I've verified that SQL Server, MySQL and SQLite  accept this syntax, there may be a slight overcharge. Avoid to use single quotations in strings is harder because of e-mail, names, etc.

Comment: If you entered '1=1' and then the server has to parse that into a numeric value, either you will end up getting an error or a numeric value (depending on the technology and the parsing strategy the server is using). How can that converted numeric value pose an SQL Injection threat?